# Execute code before returning Http result

Tags: angular

I want to execute a piece of code before returning an Http request. This is my code:

```
public getEntities(endpoint: String): Observable<T[]> {
  this.openSnackBar('Loading...');
  return this.http.get(endpoint) as Observable<T[]>; }
```

When starting the Http get request, I'm opening a snackbar which says "Loading...". I want to close this snackbar with `this.closeSnackBar()` when the Http request is done and the result is received, but before returning the result.

Is there a way to do this? I already have the code for the snackbar:

```
openSnackBar(message: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message);
  }

  closeSnackBar() {
    this.snackBar.dismiss();
  }
```

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize. Note however that what you use to open the snack bar before sending the request is not really correct: the request is sent when subscribing to the observable, not when creating it. See https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/defer

Comment: i think the best way is you should open snackbar from that function from where you are calling service function and when you get service response you can close snackbar after getting response in `observable`

Answer (score 1):

I understand you expect a body containing an array of type T in your HTTP GET response, so you might as well tell the angular HttpClient that by using generics:

```
return this.http.get<T[]>(endpoint);
```

This way, you will not have to cast to the observable you desire.

In order to achieve your expected result, you may use the `tap` operator:

```
public getEntities(endpoint: String): Observable<T[]> {
  this.openSnackBar('Loading...');
  return this.http.get<T[]>(endpoint).pipe(
    tap((res) => this.closeSnackBar());
}
```

Don't forget the imports form rxjs (`tap`).

It might be worth mentioning, that you will have to make sure to close the snack bar in case an error occurs in your HTTP request as well, see this for reference:

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

Edited on behalf of the reasonable comment by @ Karol Trybulec.

Comment: `Map`, as the name suggest, is used to manipulate elements (map smth to smth). To call external functions independent of stream it is better to use `do` or `tap`.

Comment: You're absolutely right - this is even cleaner. Let me update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Since you also want to close the snackbar on error, tap is not the appropriate operator. finalize is.